# How would I express a chained assignment in Scala?

Tags: scala, expression, variable-assignment

How would I express the following java code in scala?

```
a = b = c;
```

By the way, I'm re-assigning variables (not declaring).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The closest shortcut syntax in Scala can only be used when you declare a `var` or `val`.

```
scala> val c = 1  
c: Int = 1

scala> val a, b = c
a: Int = 1
b: Int = 1
```

From the Scala Reference, Section 4.1

> A value declaration val x<sub>1</sub> , ... ,
>   x<sub>n</sub>: T is a shorthand for the sequence
>   of value declarations val x<sub>1</sub>: T ;
>   ...; val x<sub>n</sub>: T. A value deﬁnition
>   val p<sub>1</sub>, ..., p<sub>n</sub> = e is a
>   shorthand for the sequence of value
>   deﬁnitions val p<sub>1</sub> = e ; ...; val p<sub>n</sub>
>   = e .  A value deﬁnition val p<sub>1</sub>, ... , p<sub>n</sub> : T = e is a shorthand for the
>   sequence of value  deﬁnitions val p<sub>1</sub>
>   : T = e ; ...; val p<sub>n</sub>: T = e .

This doesn't work for re-assignement to a `var`. The C/Java style doesn't work for reasons explained here: [What is the Motivation for Scala Assignment Evaluating to Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-va)

Comment: Note that the expression on the right-hand-side will be evaluated several times (once per a variable): e.g. `a` and `b` in `val a, b = new Object` will refer to different objects.

Answer (score 5):

Using the fact that the left-hand-side of an assignment is syntactically a pattern. (See PatVarDef > PatDef > Pattern2 in [SLS](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf).)

a = b = 5

```
scala> val a@b = 5
a: Int = 5
b: Int = 5
```

x = y = z = new Object

```
scala> var x@(y@z) = new Object
x: java.lang.Object = java.lang.Object@205144
y: java.lang.Object = java.lang.Object@205144
z: java.lang.Object = java.lang.Object@205144
```

Note that the expression on the right-hand-site is evaluated only once.

Unfortunately, this syntax doesn't work for **re**assigning (so for `x = y = value` you still have to do `x = value; y = x`).

See also [[scala-language] Chained assignment in Scala](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/dd8c958ffa86de49)

Answer (score 1):

The "return type" of the expression (assignment) `b = c` is `Unit`, I'm afraid, which means this syntax is not valid.

Answer (score 1):

```
b = c; a = b
```

Awkward, I know. That's Scala pretty much telling you "don't do that". Consider it the Scala version of Python's space identation for block delimitation.

Answer (score -1):

```
val b = c
val a = b
```

You can't write

```
val a = b = c
```

since that defines an expression

Comment: or `var`, when the variable is variable and not final.

Comment: Isn't there a shorthand? It seems stupid having to write b = c; a = b