# Equal Sign and Type Mismatch

Tags: scala, syntax

When working with the standard widget toolkit ([SWT](http://eclipse.org/swt)), I usually use something like this to define my `GridLayout`:

```
layout.marginTop = layout.marginBottom = 
    layout.marginLeft = layout.marginRight =
        layout.horizontalSpacing = layout.verticalSpacing = 20
```

It works in java but not in scala.
It gives me `type mismatch; Found: Unit Required: Int`.

So how can this solve it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot do this in one line in scala because the result type of an assignment expression (e.g. `a = b`) is `Unit`. You'd have to have 6 separate calls:

```
layout.marginTop = 20
layout.marginBottom = 20 
... etc
```

Why is the result type of an assignment `Unit` and nmot the assigned value? I believe this was chosen for performance reasons [as outlined in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-va).

There is a [related question on assignment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442318/how-would-i-express-a-chained-assignment-in-scala) which points out that at *declaration site*, it is possible via:

```
val a, b, c = X
```

Comment: ...and I thought scala is about syntactic sugar and "type less, do more" philosophy :/

Comment: @phineas If you want to type less to do more in SWT, be sure to check out Dave Orme's [XScalaWT](http://www.coconut-palm-software.com/the_new_visual_editor/doku.php?id=blog:simplifying_swt_with_scala) library.

Comment: @phineas - this is one of those very few areas where Java can be more concise. Note that the example you gave is a rather nasty case of bad encapsulation, however! It's a code pattern that I would see immediately as a "smell"

Comment: I have to admit, Swing is modelled a bit better (but lacks certain features).

Answer (score 1):

You have to write multiple assignments separately. As the compiler says, an assignment in Scala returns `Unit`, which can be seen as Java's `void`.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
def assign[A](a:A)(fs: (A => Unit)*) = fs.foreach(_(a))

val r = new java.awt.Rectangle
assign(20)(r.x=_, r.y=_, r.width=_, r.height=_)
```

But this is clearly worse than writing everything separately. But at least you don't have to type "layout" every time in Scala:

```
val rectangle = new java.awt.Rectangle
import rectangle._
x = 20
y = 20
width = 20
height = 20
```