# Why does assignment return Unit? (Why aren't assignments chainable?)

Tags: scala, variable-assignment, assignment-operator

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

I was just wondering why an assignment in Scala returns Unit. It would be pretty useful if it returned the value assigned, so that we could chain assignments, like this:

```
val a = b = c = 9
```

I'm sure there must be a reason.

Comment: This is mostly a duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v) stack overflow question, but it is also useful to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2442318/how-would-i-express-a-chained-assignment-in-scala) one with a limited workaround.

Comment: Why would you ever want to assign three immutable vals to the same value? :) Anyway, `val a, b, c = 9`

Comment: +1 'cause you're right, that was a lousy example...