# Incrementing and getting value

Tags: scala

Simple scala question. Consider the below.

```
scala> var mycounter: Int = 0;
mycounter: Int = 0

scala> mycounter += 1

scala> mycounter
res1: Int = 1
```

In the second statement I increment my counter. But nothing is returned.  How do I increment and return something in one statement.

Comment: You don't. Side-effecting methods or expressions will, as a general rule, not return an interesting value, only `Unit`.

Comment: @Randall Schulz good point about side effecting.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using '+=' [return Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v), so you should do:

```
{ mycounter += 1; mycounter }
```

You can too do the trick using a closure (as function parameters are val):

```
scala> var x = 1
x: Int = 1

scala> def f(y: Int) = { x += y; x}
f: (y: Int)Int

scala> f(1)
res5: Int = 2

scala> f(5)
res6: Int = 7

scala> x
res7: Int = 7
```

BTW, you might consider using an immutable value instead, and embrace this programming style, then all your statements will return something ;)

Comment: Good post. But in my my case I am using a counter which means I can't make it fully immutable.

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can, would you mind sharing a pastie with the full use case?

Comment: Oh ok, mutating state in actor (seen you comment on other post), then definitely make sense.

Comment: did something change in Scala these years? I'm able to do what the OP wasn't able to do when this post was written. EDIT: I'm running "Scala version 2.11.7 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_45)"

Answer (score 7):

Sometimes I do this:

```
val nextId = { var i = 0; () => { i += 1; i} }
println(nextId())                               //> 1
println(nextId())                               //> 2
```

Might not work for you if you need sometime to access the value *without* incrementing.

Answer (score 1):

Assignment is an expression that is evaluated to Unit. Reasoning behind it can be found here: [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

In Scala this is usually not a problem because there probably is a different construct for the problem you are solving.

I don't know your exact use case, but if you want to use the incrementation it might be in the following form:

```
(1 to 10).foreach { i => 
  // do something with i
}
```

Comment: my exact case is I have an Actor which encapsulates a counter.  Every time it is sent a message it increases in value.

Comment: I see, that is a good place for a `var`. In that case you might create a method as Alois Cochard suggested: `def increment:Int = { counter += 1; counter }`