# Scala - While Loop: increment with `+=` type mismatch error (found: Unit, required: Int)

Tags: scala, while-loop, type-mismatch

New to Scala coming from Java, and trying to understand it by converting a Java program into Scala.

Right now, I'm re-coding a merge function that is primarily a while loop in Java.  Here's what I have right now:

```
def merge(index: Int): Unit = {
    val len: Int = master.length + div(index).length
    var res = Array.ofDim[Long](len)
    var sign = Array.ofDim[Boolean](len)
    var i: Int = 0
    var j: Int = 0
    var resi: Int = 0
    while (i < master.length || j < div(index).length) {
      if (i == master.length) {
        res(resi) = div(index)(j)
        sign(resi += 1) = parity(index)(j += 1)
      }
      else if (j == div(index).length) {
        res(resi) = master(i)
        sign(resi += 1) = masterp(i += 1)
      }
      else if (master(i) < div(index)(j)) {
        res(resi) = master(i)
        sign(resi += 1) = masterp(i += 1)
      }
      else {
        res(resi) = div(index)(j)
        sign(resi += 1) = parity(index)(j += 1)
      }
    master = res
    masterp = sign
    }
  }
```

And right now I'm getting errors at each += use due to a type mismatch (found: Unit, required: Int).

Why is this happening here?  From my understanding, it has something to do with Scala being expression-based, but I'm not entirely sure?  I have shorter while loops that do not throw this error, like:

```
var j: Int = i
while (j >= 0) {
  div(index)(j + 1) = master(j) * p
  parity(index)(j + 1) = !masterp(j)
  j -= 1
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Incrementing and getting value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14797547/incrementing-and-getting-value). Sorry, found that too late, searched for the error message; added relevant pieces of error message to title.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression `x += 1` returns a `Unit`, but that's not what you want.

If you want to return `x` after it's incremented, use

```
{ x += 1; x }
```

as in

```
sign({ resi += 1; resi }) = parity(index)({ j += 1; j })
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply!  As a quick question, is the semicolon used as a return syntax in Scala?

Comment: @kapkong No, the semicolon simply separates expressions/statements in blocks. The value of the last expression/statement in the block is returned. Therefore, in `{ j += 1; j }` , the first statement is `j += 1` , it increments the variable `j` by `1`, and the last occuring expression in the block is the updated `j`, so this is what the block returns.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!  Makes a lot more sense.  Final question, why does my 2nd while loop not throw the same error I had previously?  Is it because I decrement j at the end separately?

Comment: @kapkong You are just not using the `Unit` value returned by `j += 1` anywhere in a position where an `Int` is required. The `j + 1` is ok, because it returns an `Int`.

Comment: Thanks so much :)

Comment: @kapkong I've modified the title a little bit, hope that's easier to google now :]