# scala while loop assignment

Tags: java, scala

I'm trying to port some Java code into Scala:

```
while ((j=f('blah'))>=0) ...
```

ERROR:"value >= is not a member of Unit"

Is this not possible?

Comment: If you really need that, you're doin it rong...

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Assignments return `()` (unit) in Scala.  But that's okay because you can put a code block anywhere.  You need this instead:

```
while ({ j=f("blah"); j } >= 0) ...
```

Comment: The reasoning for that can be found here: [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)