# Scala - the assignment associativity of "val a = b = c"

Tags: scala

As I read from book, scala operator associativity comes from left to right except operator ends with ":" char.

Given the `val a = b = c`, it becomes `val a = (b = c)` and makes `a` is initialized as Unit.

But why does not it become `(val a = b) = c`, and it cause that compile error because to use a Unit(returned from `a=b`) to receive `c`?

And after I really types `(val a = b) = c`, the compiler complains `illeagal start of simple expression` and pointers to `val`. Why are these two assignment operators not grouped from left to right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The important thing to see here is that `val a = b = c` is a declaration and not an expression, but precedence and associativity are notions applying to expressions.

Looking at the [Scala 2.11 Language Specification, 4.1 Value Declarations and Definitions](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/04-basic-declarations-and-definitions.html#value-declarations-and-definitions), you can see that

```
val a = b = c
```

is a basic declaration falling into the `PatVarDef` case, so it can be read as (simplifying the [`Pattern2`](http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/08-pattern-matching.html#patterns) part to the specific case of `varid` here):

```
'val' varid '=' Expr
```

Thus, here we have

- the variable identifier `varid` is `a`,
- the expression `Expr` is `b = c`,
- `a` is assigned the value `b = c` evaluates to, which happens to be `Unit`.

For the later see [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

Note that the above assumes that `b` is a `var`, e.g.,

```
val c = 17
var b = 3
val a = b = c
```

as `b` is reassigned in the third line (else you would get `error: reassignment to val`). If you want to assign the same value to two `val` for some reason, you can use

```
val c = 17
val a, b = c
```

Comment: "> Evaluation of the value definition implies evaluation of its right-hand side e"
 It looks like it resolves the `value definition`("val a = E") first then evaluates the right-hand side of `expression E` ("b = c"), then assign the `result of E to a`. Thanks

Comment: on my system 2.11.6, if they are vals it croaks, vars ok for b and c, or b at least,  cuz it wants to set b to value of c. a is left as (). It's gonna stomp on b.