# Return type of bindFromRequest.fold

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

My feeble Scala skills have me baffled about the right way to do something.  The code below compiles (and works) only when I include the `t match {...` line.  If I eliminate that line and of course, the diagnostic `println` on the preceding line, I get the compile time error as shown.  Apparently the compiler regards the return of the fold as Unit (surprise to me).  That might be reasonable, but I don't understand it.  Would someone please enlighten me about a better way to code this, and perhaps give me more insight?

```
[error] /home/bill/activator/cherry/app/controllers/Application.scala:34: type mismatch;
[error]  found   : Unit
[error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result
[error]   }
[error]   ^
```

Source:

```
  def ptweets = Action { implicit request =>
    import play.api.data._
    val rqForm = Form(Forms.mapping(
      "k" -> Forms.number,
      "who" -> Forms.text,
      "what" -> Forms.text)(TweetInquiry.apply)(TweetInquiry.unapply))
    val t = rqForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest("That's not good"),
      rq =>  Ok((views.html.properForm("POST tweets TBD.")(Html("<em>Blah</em>"))))
    ) // expect a play.api.mvc.Result
    println(t.getClass.getName) // this confirms it in both run-time cases
    t match { case v:Result => v } // yet this is required for compile
  }
```

Comment: Remove the assignment to val?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as m-z said in the comments, change

```
val t = rqForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest("That's not good"),
      rq =>  Ok((views.html.properForm("POST tweets TBD.")(Html("<em>Blah</em>"))))
    ) // expect a play.api.mvc.Result
    println(t.getClass.getName) // this confirms it in both run-time    cases
    t match { case v:Result => v } // yet this is required for compile
```

to just:

```
rqForm.bindFromRequest.fold(
      formWithErrors => BadRequest("That's not good"),
      rq =>  Ok((views.html.properForm("POST tweets TBD.")(Html("<em>Blah</em>"))))
   )
```

The fold is evaluating to a Result, but in the code you posted, you're assigning that Result to the value t. Thus, instead of the Action block evaluating to the result of the fold, it's evaluating to an assignment (which is Unit, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)).