# About scala *= operator‘s return value

Tags: scala

I am learning Scala as a personal interest and I'm perplexed by the return value of the following:

```
var t : Long = 1
def product(s:String):Long = {
    if(s.length > 1) t *= product(s.tail)
    else  t *= s.toLong 
}
```

This is a recursive function，but the compiler tall me two errors that：

```
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Long
       if(s.length > 1) t *= product(s.tail)
                          ^
<console>:14: error: type mismatch;
 found   : Unit
 required: Long
       else  t *= s.toLong 
               ^
```

and in scala-doc ,i can't find the def *= in Long.

Comment: What is `t`?  Where is it defined?

Comment: sorry var t :Long = 1

Answer (score 2):

`t *= product(s.tail)` is shorthand for `t = t * product(s.tail)`

If you want to return he value of t, you have to do it explicitly:

```
var t : Long = 1
def product(s:String):Long = {
    if(s.length > 1) t *= product(s.tail)
    else  t *= s.toLong 

    t
}
```

But seeing you are side-effecting t here, it is not really in the spirit of functinal programming.

I prefer a pure function:

```
def product(s:String, t: Long):Long = {
    if(s.length > 1) t * product(s.tail, t)
    else  t * s.toLong 
}
```

Comment: There might be a good reason to use a mutable variable. There's not enough context to say that, IMO.

Comment: recursive call of `product` is incorrect here, it should have two arguments, like `product(s.tail, t)`

Answer (score 1):

The `x *= e` construct returns `Unit`

```
scala> var t : Long = 1
t: Long = 1

scala> :type t *= 42
Unit

scala>
```

Answer (score 0):

`t *= …` is, if not overloaded, a shorthand for `t = t * …` - a simple assigment. And since those [have `Unit` return type](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1998724/1048572) instead of yielding the new value (`Long`), you're getting a type error here (twice).

Changing your function to the following should work:

```
def product(s:String): Long = {
    t *= if(s.length > 1) product(s.tail) else s.toLong
    t
}
```

However you probably should either change the return type to `Unit` if you only care about the side effect of changing `t` anyway:

```
var t: Long = 1
def product(s:String): Unit = {
    t *= if(s.length > 1) product(s.tail) else s.toLong
}
```

or make the function pure and not mutate the variable:

```
val t: Long = 1
def product(s:String): Long =
    t * if(s.length > 1) product(s.tail) else s.toLong
```

Answer (score 0):

Assignment expression (using "=" sign) returns nothing, which we can call it `Unit` in `Scala`.

`*=` means `*` first and then make assignment. Therefore, you actually returns `Unit`, not Long.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the expression `*=`, you are creating a side-effect that modifies the variable on the left side, in this case, `t`. Because a side-effect by its very nature has no return value, the Scala compiler tells you that you have a type mismatch, specifically, that `Unit` does not conform to `Long`.

Since `t` carries the value that you want, where `product` modifies `t`, `t` needs to be explicitly returned by `product`. Placing it in the last line makes it the return value (Scala does not require writing `return t`, but you could; it is equivalent either way). Others have posted their fixes, but in situations like this, consider doing this:

```
var t : Long = 1
def product(s:String) = {
  if(s.length > 1) t *= product(s.tail)
  else  t *= s.toLong
  t  //Made t the return, which is what you want.
}
```

and working through your definitions from there. This does not compile, but it shows you the next step. Think about how to make `product` return `t` in all cases. Think carefully about how you are using recursion.