# What was the reason for Swift assignment evaluation to void?

Tags: swift, language-design, assignment-operator

This question is about **HISTORY** (not your current opinions on the matter).

While reading post about dropping support for increment/decrement operators for Swift I read such text "Swift already deviates from C in that the =, += and other assignment-like operations returns Void (for a number of reasons)".

So at some time in the past developers consciously decided to evaluate assignments to void for some reasons.

And I am looking for those **historical** (now) reasons. Pretty much as this thread is about historical reasons for [Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v).

Comment: Could you provide a link to the article about dropping support for increment/decrement please? I'm interested in reading it.

Comment: @FreeNickname, sure, take a look: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0004-remove-pre-post-inc-decrement.md

Comment: in C you can use something like if i=1 {}. the result of an assignment returns value which you can use. in swift such statements will not compile and the reason (i think so) is to avoid unwanted side effect.  i can agree with this idea, on the opposite side i really don't see, why ++i, i++. --i, i-- should be removed from the language. i read the article at least twice and it is still not very clear to me.

Comment: @user3441734, it might be the reason, however I don't think it is. Because in Swift only boolean expressions are accepted in `if`, if I'm not mistaken. So even if `i = 1` returned `if`, `if i = 1 {}` wouldn't compile, since in Swift `1` is not a boolean value. @greenoldman, thank you for the link)

Comment: I can't talk specifically about Swift, but some people consider using an expression for both its value and its side-effect a bad practice, because such code is hard to understand. It can also lead to code like `i = ++i + i++;`, which has undefined behavior in C and C++.

Answer (score 16):

At least one reason is to be safer in comparison operations. When writing in C, Objective-C, etc., how many times have you written this:

```
if (x = 2)
```

instead of

```
if (x == 2)
```

Newer versions of compilers have introduced specific warnings for the above case, but wow has that one missing equal sign caused hard-to-identify bugs in my code over the years.

With the Swift type system, this would be less of a problem, since the returned value would most likely not comply to the BooleanType protocol, but if it did (`if x = false`), you might still hit these bugs. A lot of Swift is designed to eliminate common causes of bugs that people have encountered, including this one.

This is stated in the Swift Programming Language book, under ["Basic Operators"](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html):

> Unlike the assignment operator in C and Objective-C, the assignment
>   operator in Swift does not itself return a value. The following
>   statement is not valid:
>
> ```
> if x = y {
>     // this is not valid, because x = y does not return a value
> }
> ```
>
> This feature prevents the assignment operator (=) from being used by
>   accident when the equal to operator (==) is actually intended. By
>   making if x = y invalid, Swift helps you to avoid these kinds of
>   errors in your code.

Comment: I never in my life (30+ years as developer) made this error, but I wrote a lot of x=y=2 like code. I feel punished for the errors of others :-)