# Why this is happening in Swift?

Tags: swift, operators

```
let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    print("conunter \(counter += 1)")
}
```

Output:

```
conunter ()
conunter ()
conunter ()
.........
```

But if I do this

```
 let _ = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 2.0, repeats: true) { (timer) in
    counter += 1
    print("conunter \(counter)")
}
```

It produces expected result. Why this is happening?

Comment: Somewhat related: [What was the reason for Swift assignment evaluation to void?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34173084/what-was-the-reason-for-swift-assignment-evaluation-to-void).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the particular function of the [`+=`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric/2885744) operator has type `inout Int` and an `Int`, and returns `()`, a.k.a. `Void`

This is an intentional design decision implemented to discourage the use of mutating side-effects within other expressions. Your case is pretty much exactly what they hoped to prevent.

It may be annoying to have one extra line for this, but consider this: is it really the job of a `print` statement to increment a variable? That doesn't sound like "printing" to me.

Comment: thanks for your explanation. Could you give me some reference so that I can lear more about this.

Comment: @Md.MuzahidulIslam https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/numeric

Comment: Thanks @Alexander

Answer (score 0):

So basically `+=` this is an operator overloading method just like `c++` so it is a function that return type `Void ()` mentioned by above answer, so it is print `conunter ()`.

After performing the function statement it assigns the value of the `counter` so much easier to understand this, the second use of `counter` will have the value.