# scala yield gives unexpected result

Tags: scala, yield

I tried following two versions of code to understand how yield in scala works. I am unable to understand why I am getting two different results

In this version, I call yield and the expression is simply multiply by 2. I get a Vector of 1st 10 multiples of 2. It makes sense to me

```
scala> val r = for (j <- 1 to 10) yield {
     | (j*2).toString //multiply by 2
     | }
r: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[String] = Vector(2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20) // got multiples of 2. This looks ok
```

Interestingly in this version, all I have done is store the multiplication by 2 in a val. But now I get an empty vector! Why is this?

```
scala> val r = for (j <- 1 to 10) yield {
     | val prod = (j*2).toString //multiply by 2 but store in a val
     | }
r: scala.collection.immutable.IndexedSeq[Unit] = Vector((), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), (), ())  //this is empty
```

I thought that maybe the val prod = (j*2).toString results in a Unit result but when I try following independent expression on scala interpreter, I can see that prod is a String

```
scala> val prod = 2.toString()
prod: String = 2
```

Comment: You need to return something from the lamba - your lambda does not return anything - it is therefore a `void` type or `Unit` in Scala. Add `prod` on a line after the `val` and it will implicitly be returned.

Comment: @BoristheSpider is right. `val prod` is created and abandoned 10 times so the `yield` has nothing to yield after each iteration.

Comment: To put it another way, `prod` is indeed a string, but `val prod = ...` is of type `Unit`. So the Vector in the second example is of type Vector[Unit].

Comment: in your second statement, you need to add `prod` after the last line for it to serve as the return value. All you are doing in the last line is set a value but return nothing, hence the `Unit` output.

Answer (score 0):

In Scala every expression return something. But assignments are designed to return `Unit` for performance reasons (see [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)).

In your snippet, in last example REPL says `prod: String = 2`, meaning that `prod` has some value, that's done for your convenience. But try `{ val prod = 2.toString() }`:

```
scala> { val prod = 2.toString() }

scala> println(res0)
()
```

`()` is the only possible value of `Unit` type.

(I'm not sure why `res0` was not shown after first like, because `resN`-like values in REPL collect all non-assigned explicitly results)