# Why Scala last val is not the return value?

Tags: scala

Generally, in Scala the return keyword is not required when returning a value and the last value is always the return value.

For example:

```
  def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    a + b
  }
```

Will return and `Int` of `a+b`.

But, why when assigning the sum to another `val` it won't be considered as a return value?

For example:

```
  def sum(a: Int, b: Int): Int = {
    val sum = a + b
  }
```

Will show type mismatch error (expected `Int`, got `Unit`). What is the reason / logic behind this behavior?

**Edit**: As I learned from the comments and the answers, it's not that Scala last val is not the return value, it is the return value. But, val assignment returns `Unit` and not the assigned type. The reason for this is: [What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

Comment: Could you kindly past error you have??

Comment: Thanks for commenting. It's a known error/behavior of mismatched type. the last val isn't considered as return value. I'm curious about the reason for this behavior.

Comment: typer inference error?? how compiler would cast Unit to Int?

Comment: The last expression is the return value, but the type of `val sum = a + b` has type `Unit` while you claim to return type `Int`.

Comment: But `sum` is `Int`. Why it won't used as return value? It's the last in the block...

Comment: val sum = a + b is expression which returns Unit ... see comment above

Comment: Ok, thanks. It's not clear to me why `val sum = a + b` return Unit :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because assignment in Scala evaluates to `Unit`, as can be demonstrated:

```
Welcome to Scala 2.12.3 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_112).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala> val y = { val x = 4 }
y: Unit = ()
```

Note that this is different to Java:

```
jshell> int x, y
x ==> 0
y ==> 0

jshell> x = (y = 4)
x ==> 4
```

Why scala chose this [has been answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

Comment: While related, I think Java example `x = (y = 4)` is not the same as Scala `val y = { val x = 4 }`. Java `int y = 4` is not even expression, it certainly does not return a value of `y`.

Comment: Thanks, the answer you linked to was exactly what I needed. I have elaborated the q in express this knowledge and the root for my confusion. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v

Comment: @Suma - I don't really understand your point; at what point did I write `int y = 4`?