# Why is this Scala code with assignment of a val in a parameter working?

Tags: scala

```
object Main {

  def main(args: Array[String])
  {
    val x = 10
    print(x="Hello World")
    print(x)
  }
}
```

> output : Hello World10

As we know, in Scala a `val` cannot be reassigned or changed, but here `x` is changing to

> Hello World

while printing.

Comment: it is not reassigning the value. It is just printing "Hello World" from first statement and 10 from second statement. Use println() and you'll see output in new line.

Answer (score 71):

Explanation is kind of unexpected: `print` has a parameter named `x`. Using `x = ...` uses the [named argument](https://docs.scala-lang.org/tour/named-arguments.html), therefore `print(x="Hello World")` is the same as `print("Hello World")`.

See [Scala Predef docs](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Predef$.html#print(x:Any):Unit) or [Predef.scala](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/02e985d2145883642a3bd98e3c1a7b3beaaab842/src/library/scala/Predef.scala#L371) source:

```
object Predef /*....*/ {

/*....*/
  def print(x: Any) = Console.print(x)

/*....*/
}
```

Note: this was already discussed in [Scala Internal mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-internals/MujIVZgbwEM):

> Scala currently tries to be smart about treating "x = e" as a named argument or an assignment
>   ... This can be surprising to the user ....
>
> Proposal: we deprecate assignments in argument lists

There also [exists an issue SI-8206](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/8206) for this, the change was probably implemented in [issue 426](https://github.com/scala/scala-dev/issues/426) for Scala 2.13.

Your code will still compile after deprecation, with the same meaning. The change will be no one (at least no one sufficiently familiar with the language specs / implementation) should expect it to be interpreted as assignment any more.

Comment: So it means this is working specifically only with variable  `x`, doesn't it?

Comment: yes, its amazing it works only for x!. thats strange.

Comment: Another thing to note is that, if you had, e.g. `var m = 12; print(m = 13); print(m);`, you'd get "()13". As for why, there is an official explanation and some other nice insights here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/1998724/5236247