# SCALA Type mismatch error List as arguement and Integer as Return

Tags: scala, type-mismatch

I am new to SCALA. I don't understand why I am getting this error when giving a return type of `Int`:

> "Type Mismatch found unit required Int"

I am passing a list as an argument to a function and return type should be `Int` as per my understanding. However eclipse throws an error.

Note: Code works fine if I remove `Int` as return but I don't understand why this is so as my last statement in the function body is returning an `Int`.

```
object ListFunctions {

  def main (args:Array[String]) {

    var listinp = List(1,2,3,4,5)
    var lastitem:Int = 0

    def ListFn (arg:List[Int]):Int = {  
      lastitem = arg.last 
    }

    ListFn(listinp)
  }
}
```

Comment: An assignment (`x = 5`) does not return the value type. It has a `Unit` return type.

Answer (score 1):

This StackOverflow article may help explain the reasoning that the return value is Unit instead of Int.

[What is the motivation for Scala assignment evaluating to Unit rather than the value assigned?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1998724/what-is-the-motivation-for-scala-assignment-evaluating-to-unit-rather-than-the-v)

In your case the simple solution is to return "arg.last"