# Scala type of statements?

Tags: java, scala, class, types

I thought that Scala classifies statements as type Unit. But when I run the following code:

```
object HelloWorld {
  var ball = new Ball

  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    println((ball.color = "green").getClass)
  }
}

class Ball {
  var color: String = "blue"
}
```

The output is

```
void
```

I have learned that void is only used in Scala for compatibility with Java. So why is void here used as type of this statement and not Unit?

Comment: Just to clarify a bit: in Scala, `ball.color = "green"` is an expression. It can be used as a statement, but in `(ball.color = "green").getClass` it isn't; only the entire `println(...)` is a statement here. If you try it with a statement which can't be an expession, e.g. `(var ball = new Ball).getClass()`, you'll see that you can't call a method on a statement and they don't have types.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov By the way `{var ball = new Ball}.getClass()` will be `void`. But `{var ball = new Ball}` is actually `{var ball = new Ball; ()}`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`getClass` comes from Java. If you jump to the definition of `getClass` in your IDE you'll get to [`java.lang.Object#getClass`](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/master/src/java.base/share/classes/java/lang/Object.java#L67)

```
public final native Class<?> getClass();
```

If you use Scala [reflection](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html) you'll see that the type is `Unit`

```
//libraryDependencies += scalaOrganization.value % "scala-reflect" % scalaVersion.value
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
def getType[T: TypeTag](t: T): Type = typeOf[T]

getType(ball.color = "green") // Unit
```

*Class* and *type* of a value are different concepts.

https://typelevel.org/blog/2017/02/13/more-types-than-classes.html

Answer (score 4):

The *compile-time* type of assignment expression is `Unit`

```
val x: Unit = (ball.color = "green")
```

and the string representation of the corresponding *runtime* class is `void`

```
().getClass
// res1: Class[Unit] = void
```

I guess assignment is considered a [side-effect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2000129/5205022) and side-effects are expressed with `Unit` type.